# Angular mouse events stopped working on firefox only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, requirejs

I am working on a site built with angular and requireJs as file dependency.
A strange thing happened, suddnly for no apperent reason ng-click/ng-mouseover/ng-mouseout stopped working on firefox. They keep working normally on IE10 and Chrome.
The page renders normally, using controllers and services, i get no Errors, and binding works.
Its only ng-events that don't work and only on firefox. anyone has an idea why is this happening??? i tried using data-ng-event but that dosn't work eather.

```
HTML:    
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="item in data">
       <a href="#" data-barid="" data-ng-click="clicked()" data-ng-mouseover="activateBar(item.id)" data-ng-mouseout="defuseBar(item.id)">
            {{item.name}}
       </a>
    </button>
</div>

JS
define([],function(){
function MainPage($scope,$http,horizontalBarChart,verticaltalBarChart){
    $scope.data={}; 
    $scope.title = 'title';
    $scope.subtitle = 'subtitle';
    $scope.activateBar = function(id){
        horizontalBarChart.activateBar(id);
    }
    $scope.defuseBar = function(id){
        horizontalBarChart.defuseBar(id);
    }

    $scope.clicked = function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
    //horizontalBarChart.init($scope,'horizon');
}
MainPage.$inject = ['$scope','$http','horizontalBarChart','verticaltalBarChart'];
return MainPage;
});
```

Comment: Anybody has any idea ? I have no script Errors, I reinstalled firefox.
Script works perfectly in all other browsers including Opera,Chrome and IE10. No one had this problem?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i got the issue, for some unknown reason, which i'll try to research further, binding mouse event directives to elements dont work well in ng-repeat loops. It works in chrome just fine, but fails to work in firefox & IE. I suspect it has something to do with the preformance rate of the JS engine of the browser. Chromes JS engine is the fastest as of today, and it might manage the repeated  parsing of elements an the attachment of seperate event listeners to them better.

So to fix this problem i am using event delegation, attaching the ng-click/ng-mouseevent to the wraping element, catching the bubling mouse events on the wrap and handling it there.
This is also an overall good practice for attaching multiple event handlers for preformance.
The wrap will catch all the child elements events and will use a factory function to trigger the right function defined on $scope. You can determine what was the element clicked using the event object.

Comment: I have the same issue in a recursive tree structure but it works fine in IE and Chrome. Firefox is the only troublemaker.